# Simple message passing Nodejs server accepting only 4 requests at a time

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, scalability

We have a simple express node server deployed on windows server 2012 that recieves GET requests with just 3 parameters. It does some minor processing on these parameters, has a very simple in-memory node-cache for caching some of these parameter combinations, interfaces with an external license server to fetch license for the requesting user and sets it in the cookie, followed by which, it interfaces with some workers via a load balancer (running with zmq) to download some large files (in chunks, and unzips and extracts them, writes them to some directories) and display them to the user. On deploying these files, some other calls to the workers are initiated as well.

The node server does not talk to any database or disk. It simply waits for response from the load balancer running on some other machines (these are long operations taking typically between 2-3 minutes to send response). So, essentially, the computation and database interactions happens on other machines. The node server is only a simple message passing/handshaking server that waits for response in event handlers, initiates other requests and renders the response.

We are not using a 'cluster' module or nginx at the moment. With a bare bones node server, is it possible to accept and process atleast 16 requests simultaneously ? Pages such as these http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2016/03/23/how-to-scale-a-nodejs-app-based-on-number-of-users/ mention that a simple node server can handle only 2-9 requests at a time. But even with our bare bones implementation, not more than 4 requests are accepted at a time.

Is using a cluster module or nginx necessary even for this case ? How to scale this application for a few hundred users to begin with ?

Comment: If not more than 4 requests are accepted at a time, it sounds like your app is running into some sort of imposed limitation (like a connection pool that's running out of connections and waiting for a connection to free up). There's too many moving parts in your story to pinpoint a culprit, but start by removing parts of your request handler to see which one may be causing the block (also, the blog post you link to doesn't actually state that a single Node server can handle only 2-9 requests at a time).

Answer (score 1):

An Express server can handle many more than 9 requests at a time, especially if it isn't talking to a datebase.

The article you're referring to assumes some database access on each request and serving static assets via node itself, rather than a CDN. All of this taking place on a single CPU with 1GB of RAM. That's a database and web server all running on a single core with minimal RAM.

There really are not hard numbers on this sort of thing; You build it and see how it performs. If it doesn't perform well enough, put a reverse proxy in front of it like nginx or haproxy to do load balancing.

However, based on your problem, if you really are running into bottlenecks where only 4 connections are possible at a time, it sounds like you're keeping those connections open way too long and blocking others. Better to have those long running processes kicked off by node, close the connections, then have those servers call back somehow when they're done.

Comment: makes sense. but, what we are doing is create a zmq req socket for almost each request (unless it  is cached already). And essesntially wait for a response on this socket inside socket.on('message'). When you say, 'close the connections' and have the workers call back when they are done, like a fire and forget model, how to implement this with zmq sockets ?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the original question.